# how to get wifi working in ubuntu 14.4

Tags: wireless

Trying to get wifi working. Here are the results from the lspci -knn grep Net -A2 command:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel corporation device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
Subsystem: Intel corporation device [8086:4010]
Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek semiconductor co., ltd. RTL8101E/RTL 8102E PCI Express fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
```

Whatever that means. ...thanks!

Just installed ubuntu 14.4. I'm going to give it a go before i consider buying another windows 7 disc.

Anyway. I'm a complete newbie. First things first. ..i can't update any settings or search for programs etc. As my ubuntu laptop can't connect to the working wifi that i'm currently using to type this on my phone.

So how do i do this?  Please remember that any answers would have to be idiot proof. For example you can't change the gear on a car if you don't even know how to locate the gear stick.

So in short...i need to access my wifi which isn't showing up anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; all comments on this question, and the entire conversation, have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42582/discussion-on-question-by-strider-how-to-get-wifi-working-in-ubuntu-14-4).